# Are there any internal differences between compound char arrays and string literals?

Tags: c, string

Is there any internal differences between this:

```
(const char[]){'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}
```

and

```
"Hello"
```

in C?
I have noticed that string literals declared with quotes are gotten by the `strings` unix command, but the others aren't. What are the internal differences that cause that?

Comment: The `strings` command searches for null-terminated strings, which quoted literals have but array literals won’t unless you add the null terminator yourself.

Comment: _compound char array_ --> _compound literal_.

Comment: @Dai strings does not search for null-terminated strings. It prints consecutive "printable" characters, 4 by default.

Comment: Your 2 objects differ in *constness*: the 1st is const-qualified, the 2nd one isn't.

Answer (score 5):

String literals always have static storage duration, whereas compound literals at block scope have automatic storage duration.

String literals have special status in initializers, e.g.

```
char x[5] = "foo";  // ok
char y[5] = (char[]){'f','o','o','\0'};   // error
```

String literals do not necessarily have unique addresses, e.g. `"foo" == "foo"` may or may not be true, and `"foo" + 1 == "oo"` may or may not be true, whereas similar comparison for compound literals must be false.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because the `strings` command looks for string literals within the object file and when you declare a string with `char *str="Hello"`, your compiler saves it as a string literal and labels it. GCC shows this memory location with the `.string` keyword, whereas clang uses `.asciz`.

On the other hand, when you declare the string as an array of chars, they are stored in the memory as consecutive bytes and are not marked with `.string` or '.asciz`

Take this simple function

```
int test() {
    (const char[]){'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0};
    char *str="Hello";
}
```

below is the code generated by GCC(without any code optimisations). clang gives a similar code but the one from GCC is simpler, so I am using it for the sake of simplicity

```
.LC0:
        .string "Hello"
test:
      push    rbp                                 ; function prologue
      mov     rbp, rsp                            ; function prologue
      mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-14], 72               ; ASCII H
      mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-13], 101              ; ASCII e
      mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-12], 108              ; ASCII l
      mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-11], 108              ; ASCII l
      mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-10], 111              ; ASCII o
      mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-9], 0                 ; ASCII null 
      mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0 ; string literal
      nop
      pop     rbp
      ret
```

After the [function prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue), the bytes are moved to memory one by one but are not marked as a string. Whereas as your `char *str="Hello";` is marked with a label and I assume the `strings` utility just searches for these literals.

Answer (score -1):

String literals are often stored in a read-only section of memory, while compound literal char arrays are not.

For example, given this code:

```
char *x = (char *)(const char[]){'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0};
char *y = "Hello";
x[0] = 'X';
printf("x=%s\n", x);
y[0] = 'X';
printf("y=%s\n", y);
```

The modification to `x[0]` is successful and the modified string is printed, while the attempted change to `y[0]` results in a segfault.

Comment: This code contains a constraint violation  (there is no implicit conversion from `const char[]` to `char *`). So you are really just demonstrating that undefined behaviour is undefined

Comment: @M.M The segfault makes things undefined anyway.  Still, I added an explicit cast to clean it up.

Comment: OK although it is still undefined behaviour (modifying a const object) . Some other compiler might give different results.